# How this integral make sense?

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

I came across the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin (2x)}{x^3} \mathrm dx$$

In the textbook, this integral is done using residue theorem by replacing $\sin (2x)$ as the imaginary part of $e^{i2x}$. And the result is $-2\pi$ !

I wonder how the result can be interpreted. This is how the graph of the function look like:

[image: f(x)]

Clearly the integral is divergent. Even if it exist, it should be positive, since the major area is above x axis. 
Then what does the -ve value of integral mean ? Or what is it's geometrical interpretation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93496/discussion-on-question-by-muhsin-ibn-al-azeez-how-this-integral-make-sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [finite part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_finite_part) integral:
$$[x^{-2}] \frac {\sin 2 x} {x^3} = 2, \\
\operatorname{FP} \int_{\mathbb R} \frac {\sin 2x} {x^3} dx =
\int_{\mathbb R} \left( \frac {\sin 2x} {x^3} - \frac 2 {x^2} \right) dx =
-2 \pi.$$

Comment: Indeed; integrating by parts twice gives $$ \begin{align} \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(2x)-2x}{x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x &=-\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty(\sin(2x)-2x)\,\mathrm{d}\frac1{x^2}\\ &=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(1-\cos(2x))\,\mathrm{d}\frac1x\\ &=-2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(2x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\\ &=-2\pi \end{align} $$ However, this also follows from Simply Beautiful Art's answer because $\frac2{z^2}$ has no residue at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following contour $\gamma$:

[image]

The limit of the imaginary part of $\displaystyle\oint_\gamma\frac{e^{2iz}}{z^3}~\mathrm dz$ as $(r,R)\to(0,\infty)$ exists, and in fact, equals $-2\pi$. The integral is a little messy to compute, namely around $z=0$, where one has to take care of the fact that we want half the residue at $z=0$, and we are travelling counterclockwise. Taking the imaginary part, we get $-2\pi$, as desired.

Comment: Even if the contour passes under the origin, the integral is $-2\pi$. However, this is computed using only the residue at $0$. What other contributing term do you mean?

Comment: Integrating $\frac{e^{2iz}}{2iz^3}$ over $$ [-R,-r]\cup re^{\pi i[1,0]}\cup[r,R]\cup Re^{\pi i[0,1]} $$ encompasses no singularities, and integrating $\frac{-e^{-2iz}}{2iz^3}$ over $$ [-R,-r]\cup re^{\pi i[1,0]}\cup[r,R]\cup Re^{-\pi i[0,1]} $$ circles clockwise the singularity at $0$, which has residue $-i$. Thus, we get the integral of $\frac{\sin(2z)}{z^3}$ along $$ [-R,-r]\cup re^{\pi i[1,0]}\cup[r,R] $$ to be $-2\pi$.

Comment: Oop, my bad. Thanks @robjohn

Comment: The limit is zero, not $-2 \pi$ (I assume $-2 \pi i$ is a typo). The integral over a large semicircle $C_R$ in the upper half-plane is negligible, and the integral over $\gamma \cup C_R$ is zero by the Cauchy integral theorem.

Comment: @Maxim: please see my comment. It outlines the contour integration to show that the integral over the contour shown is $-2\pi$.

Comment: @robjohn The answer says "the limit of the imaginary part of $\int_\gamma e^{2 i z}/z^3 dz$". I'm claiming that limit is zero, not $-2 \pi$. The limit of $\int_\gamma \sin(2 z)/z^3 dz$ is indeed $-2 \pi$.

Comment: Ah, yes. In my comment, that component is zero for the contour depicted in this answer. For the contour which passes below the origin, the integral is $-2\pi$